# converting struct to char* and back

Tags: c++, struct, char

I am trying to convert my struct into a char*, and then back to a struct. But I guess I am missing something. Once it is returned to struct, only one attribute of the struct is correct. The rest is all wrong. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct INFO {
    unsigned char a;
    int b;
    int c;
    char g[121];
}inf;



int main () {
    char frame[128];

    INFO test1 = INFO();
    test1.a='y';
    test1.b=4000;
    test1.c=9000;
    strcpy(test1.g, "Goodbye World");

    sprintf(frame,(char*)&test1);

    INFO test2 = INFO();
    memcpy((char*)&test2, frame, sizeof(frame)); //shouldn't test2 have test1 values?

    cout << test2.a<<"\n";
    cout << test2.b<<"\n";
    cout << test2.c<<"\n";
    cout << test2.g<<"\n";
    getchar();
    return 0;
  }
```

Output:

```
y
-858993460
-858993460
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
```

Only test2.a is correct. Am I converting it to a char* wrong, or is it the way I convert it back? Thanks

Comment: Apart from being dreadful, you would do well to consider both the involved padding, and subsequently declaring `frame` as `char frame[sizeof(struct INFO)];` In fact, *print* that size at the top of your program, just for kicks. You're also using `sprintf()`, utterly wrong for "printing" to `frame`. The moment it runs into a zero-byte it will stop sending data (and you have plenty of zero-bytes in `b` and `c`). Finally, my curiosity for the purpose of the unused global variable `inf` is killing me.

Comment: sprintf is not a memory copy

Comment: snprintf(output,payloadsize , "%d%d%d%d",i,j,k,l)

Comment: ╠ is 0xCC in codepage 437, and [MSVC fills 0xCC to uninitialized memory to help debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714). That means you've accessed uninitialized memory. You can find tons of questions about ╠ and 0xCC here on SO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few problems with this code, but the one that's causing the problem is the use of `sprintf` to copy *binary* data from the struct to the character array: if there's a NUL byte anywhere in the struct's data the copy will stop short. In this case there's a NUL char in the struct data right after the first member, either embedded in the second member or because of padding, so only the first member is copied entirely.

Use `memcpy` instead of `sprintf`.

```
// sprintf(frame,(char*)&test1); <-- wrong
memcpy(frame, &test1, sizeof(frame));

INFO test2 = INFO();
memcpy(&test2, frame, sizeof(frame));
```

Another problem is that the size of the INFO structure is likely not 128 because of padding and alignment, so it cannot be copied entirely to `frame`. Use the `sizeof` operator to find the size.

Comment: There's also absolutely no need to cast to `char*`. `memcpy` takes a `void*`.

Comment: Why copy sizeof(frame)? Shouldn't that be sizeof(INFO)? It'd make a lot more sense if OP just did `memcpy(&test2, &test1, sizeof(INFO));`

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames, that would be a buffer overflow because here `frame` is smaller than `INFO`.

Comment: Thanks Joni it works! I know the rest of code looks bad, but it was a toy program I threw together quickly to inquire about my real problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

```
char frame[sizeof(INFO)]; // Let compiler decide size of frame

INFO test1 = INFO();
test1.a='y';
test1.b=4000;
test1.c=9000;
strcpy(test1.g, "Goodbye World");

memcpy(frame, &test1, sizeof(INFO)); // copy memory and not string
```